# Interacting with running Google Search app

Tags: android, android-activity

I am writing an app that transmits and receives data over the audio port, which requires me to start an AudioRecord instance on the mic. I have the app working on most phones, however I ran into an issue on the Droid Mini where the Google Search app has an active AudioRecord on the input source I need. This is due to the Hotword Detection being active at all times on the phone. I don't know why this is an issue on this phone only, as I have the Hotword Detection active on my phone as well (Droid RAZR M) and I have no problems getting access to the resource.

In my research on the matter, I noticed that there are permissions called com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.permission .PAUSE_HOTWORD and com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.permission .RESUME_HOTWORD which indicates to me that there is a way to pause the Hotword Detection so that another application can use that resource for something. With that in mind, I would like to be able to pause Hotword Detection when my app is actively reading data and resume it when the audio resource is no longer needed. I have looked everywhere and I can't seem to find what I need to do in order to call the routine that would actually pause the detection. Is it simply a matter of including those permissions in my manifest file, or do I need to do that and call an actual pause() and resume() function?

I ran an ADB bugreport on the affected phone and I found these entries in the report file:

```
  Action: "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.action.PAUSE_HOTWORD"

  Action: "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.action.RESUME_HOTWORD"

  requiredPermission=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.permission.PAUSE_HOTWORD
```

Again, this is essentially the action that I'm trying to accomplish - any idea how I can do that? As always, thank you in advance for your help.

-Chris